# Running rsvars.bat with TRichView components

Tags: windows, delphi, batch-file, delphi-xe2

I am trying to build my Delphi files through the command line using the rsvars.bat file provided with Delphi (I am using Delphi XE2). Most things seem to build fine but I have a few errors that arise with [TRichView](http://trichview.com/). TRichView provides a file named RVStyle.pas which defines the variable TRVTag like so:

```
  {$IFNDEF RVOLDTAGS}
  TRVTag = type String;
  {$ELSE}
  TRVTag = Integer;
  {$ENDIF}
```

This seems to be done this way to allow backwards compatibility, TRVTags were changed from Integer to String as based on this thread. http://www.trichview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6377

In one of our custom controls we pass an Integer ItemIndex into GetItemTag which is requesting TRVTag.

```
   Result := GetItemTag(ItemIndex);
```

This works fine when building the files through Delphi but when building the files through the command line I am receiving 'Incomparable type' errors. The specific error is:

```
Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'TRVTag'
```

This appears to happen a few places in our custom control, sometimes it says incompatible types 'integer' and 'TRVTag' other times it says incompatible types 'string' and 'Integer.

To me it seems like when building through the command line the build is somehow not picking up the definition of TRVTag as defined in RVStyle.pas or the

My batch file for building looks like so:

```
cd c:\frontend\v10
call rsvars.bat
MSBuild del12\del12.dproj
PAUSE
```

Is there something I can add to my batch file that would allow me to be able to build these files without incompatible type errors the same as when building through XE2 itself?

Comment: It sounds like `RVOLDTAGS` is getting defined sometimes and not others. Does your project make use of Build Configurations?  You are not specifying any configuration on the command line. Perhaps when the project is built in the IDE, you are compiling one configuration, but when built on the command line you are compiling a different configuration.

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for. As soon as I added the flags  "/t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug" to the end of the MSBUILD command everything worked.

Comment: That's the wrong solution. What you need to do is to define the conditional in the right place. It's defined only in the debug configuration. You need it defined in the root configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes that `RVOLDTAGS` is defined. You have defined it in the debug configuration, but not other configuration. Configurations use inheritance. This allows properties to be inherited by derived configurations, or to have properties defined only for some configurations, or to have properties overridden for some configurations.

In your case your code requires that `RVOLDTAGS` be defined for all configurations. So you should define it in the root configuration from which all other configurations are inherited. Remove the definition from the debug configuration and re-introduce it in the root configuration.